# Concerning an equation involving a gradient

Tags: calculus

On the last slide of [this](https://web.iem.technion.ac.il/images/user-files/becka/lec4_gradient_method.pdf) pdf the author writes

> $$\sum_{i=1}^m w_i\frac{x_k-a_i}{\|x_k-a_i\|} = \nabla f(x_k)$$

where $f$ is previously defined as $$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m w_i \|x-a_i\|$$

Could you explain why this is true? I do not get it. I suppose there has to be a relation between the gradient and the norm of vector, but I can not see which.

[image]>

Comment: why do you think that the second equation is true? I don't see it on the last slide.

Comment: I don't understand any of this, but it's hard to believe that a thing called $\nabla f(x_k)$ is independent of the choice of $i$, as in your last equation.

Comment: That **is** the gradient of the cost (where differentiable). The cost is the sum of the weighted distances, so the gradient will be the sum of the weighted gradients of $x \mapsto \|x-a_i\|$.

Comment: @SZN and Randall: I inserted a picture where I marked the step I do not understand.

Comment: @3nondatur Great--I'm still not sure why you've written the second equation, as it appears that what you actually don't understand is why the first equation you wrote is true. The first task in figuring that out is finding what $f$ is--so what is $f$?

Comment: @3nondatur we can see where you are confused, but no one believes that your second equation is correct.  (You only have a problem if the second equation is right, but if it's not.....)

Comment: Sorry I mixed things up.  will make an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$$f(\mathbf{x}):= \sum_{i=1}^m \omega_i\|\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{a}_i \|, \ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
If $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) $ and $ \mathbf{a}_i=(a_1^{(i)}, a_2^{(i)}, \ldots, a_n^{(i)})$ then we have that

$$f(\mathbf{x}):= \sum_{i=1}^m \omega_i \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j- a_j^{(i)})^2}.$$

For $k=1, \ldots, n$ we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}= \sum_{i=1}^m \omega_i \frac{x_k-a_k^{(i)}}{\|\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{a}_i \|}.$$
That implies that

$$\nabla f = \sum_{i=1}^m \omega_i \frac{\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{a}_i}{\|\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{a}_i \|} $$